# jasper reports Ireport designer element overlapping

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to generate a pdf report where the static text label is on left and the corressponding data text field  is parallely aligned to its right.

The similar way other items are arranged one below the other.

the  stretch with overflow property is set to true for text field and as it stretches , its no more aligned to the static text label to its left.

how to solve this problem.....

so that the alignement of an item in releavance with its data is visually meaningful...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, allocate some space(vertically) for the dynamic text element.Set the

> stretch when overflow property to true

. Place the dynamic component inside the frame.Compile the report and run the report.Check whether the data is now represented properly or not..I am not sure whether it would work or not but you can try it once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried the same but still the static text label does not align itself with the corresponding field, although both the report elements are in the same frame..